# Automate creation of SharePoint 2010 Search Profile Pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, sharepoint-server

Does anybody have any lead on how to automate the configuration of External Content type Profile Page host site creation (Parameterized for the site URL) as well as default actions for each entity?

I really appreciate the help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can provision a profile page anywhere you like, it does not have to be in the default location *bdc/http*_etc. All you need to do is provision a web part page with a Business Data Item Builder and a Business Data Item. The URL that you pass to the page does the rest. You should look at one of the MANY blog posts for provisioning a Web part page and the rest is pretty easy.